# HAproxy balancing based on response header

Tags: haproxy

I have AWS Route53 geo domain name and 3 AWS regions with same app but with different clients on them.

Some clients are on Region1 and some clients are on Region2 and so on.

Becase of geo based record Client from Region2 cant connect to Client from Region1 directly because it will resolve to Region2 ALB and app will response that there is no such client but it can response with Custom_header "X-Region=region1" and HTTP/410

Is it possible on HAproxy to set smthing like this:

if default backend response 200 (client was found in same region), then just proxy_pass and dont check X-Region header.

If default backend res.hdr(X-Region) -i region1, then use backend_region1 for proxy_pass

If default backend res.hdr(X-Region) -i region2, then use backend_region2 for proxy_pass

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For now I implemented that on Varnish+HAproxy:

```
vcl 4.0;

import directors;
import std;

backend eu-west-1 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

backend ap-southeast-1 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8081";
}

backend ap-southeast-2 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8082";
}

sub vcl_recv {
if (req.method == "POST"){ std.cache_req_body(5000KB);}
  set req.backend_hint = eu-west-1;
    if (req.restarts > 0 && req.http.x-region == "ap-southeast-1"){
        set req.backend_hint = ap-southeast-1;
    }
    if (req.restarts > 0 && req.http.x-region == "ap-southeast-2"){
        set req.backend_hint = ap-southeast-2;
    }
  return(pass);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if(resp.status == 410 && req.restarts < 1 && resp.http.X-Region == "ap-southeast-1")
    {
        set req.http.x-region = "ap-southeast-1";
       return(restart);
    }
    if(resp.status == 410 && req.restarts < 1 && resp.http.X-Region == "ap-southeast-2")
    {
        set req.http.x-region = "ap-southeast-2";
        return(restart);
    }
}
```

and

```
frontend eu-west-1
        bind *:8080
        use_backend eu-west-1

frontend ap-southeast-1
        bind *:8081
        use_backend ap-southeast-1

frontend ap-southeast-2
        bind *:8082
        use_backend ap-southeast-2

backend eu-west-1
        server eu-west-1 127.0.0.1:90 check
backend ap-southeast-1
        server ALB1:443 check ssl verify none
backend ap-southeast-2
        server ALB2:443 check ssl verify none
```

But i wonder if that could be done using HAproxy only.

Comment: It looks like your formatting got wrong. Parts that seem to be code are formatted as text followed by just one line of code. FYI: if you want to paste a block of code, wrap it inside tripe backticks ```

Comment: thanks a lot. fixed